# How to build JSON using a recursive ANTLR4 parse tree listener

Tags: python, json, parsing, recursion, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 to parse a structured data file and seem to have hit a wall. I know this is a very specific question, but perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm parsing files that look like this:

```
MSH
[  PD1  ]
[{ ROL }]
[
  { ROL }
]
[
    {
        PR1
        [{ ROL }]
    }
]
[
    {
        IN1
        [  IN2  ]
        [{ IN3 }]
    }
]
[ ACC ]
```

Where:

- 3 single alphanumerics represent a SEGMENT
- [ SEGMENT ] represents a Optional Segment
- { SEGMENT } represents a Repeating Segment
- [{ SEGMENT }] represents an Optional Repeating Segment
- Any of the above SEGMENT profiles can be grouped together in nesting
  Optional and/or Repeating GROUPS.
- Examples of nested repeating groups are lines 4 - 19 in the code above.

My ANTLR4 Lexer/Parser works well yielding the following Parse Tree:

[image: Parse Tree]

The end goal is to translate any dataset, using the above rules, into JSON format. Example using a few of the lines in from dataset file above:

```
{
  "MSH": {
    "name": "placeholder",
    "opt": false,
    "rep": false,
    "description": "Plain Segment"
  },
  "PD1": {
    "name": "placeholder",
    "opt": true,
    "rep": false,
    "description": "Optional Segment"
  },
  // some segments here
  "group": {
    "opt": true,
    "rep": false,
    "description": "Optionals group placeholder text",
    "segment0": {
      "ROL": {
        "name": "placeholder",
        "opt": false,
        "rep": true,
        "description": "Repeating Segment"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've generated something close to the above json using an ANTLR4 listener [implemented here.](https://pastebin.com/X51PQqVE) But its the nested groups that keep tripping me up, I'm finding it difficult to do with the Listener. Perhaps another set of eyes will help.